# Using Random To Assign Chance

Tags: python, random, module

Is there a way to set up an if statement like this where 1 if statement covers multiple integers?

```
variable = random.randrange(1,10)

if variable is between 1 - 3 
    then do this
if variable is between 4-5
    then do this
if variable is between 6-9
    then do this
```

or maybe something like this

```
a = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

variable = random.randrange(1,10)

if variable == a:
    then do this
```

Comment: You should probably just post the segment of code that is relevant to using random to assign chance.

Comment: Okay. How does it work? And what's the actual question (you are just telling me that you have troubling applying `random` module) to your game design. Describe the difficulty. What do you want to achieve? No one will read the entire program.... and do Sherlock Holmes lol.

Comment: part i'm having a problem with is at the botton (starts with the variable attack_player)

Comment: pay attention to @jamylak's comment, there's a reason 4 or more people up-voted it. This post only needs the last 10 lines, and telling people you're writing a strategy game is a good way to get your post moved off SO and onto http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RandomPhobia much better... although... what's the code on top add?

Comment: @Shep Your right I should focus on the implementation and not the reason. point taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about choosing a random number for each player, then the player with the largest value gets to attack first.

Or, if this isn't turn based, then set a threshold, and if the random number is over the threshold, then the player can attack.

The threshold could also be a random number. For example:

```
player1.attack = randn ()
[player2 etc]
minval = randn ()
for player in players:
  if player.attack > minval:
    [...attack...]
```

The question at the bottom is easy to implement, basically exactly as you've written it:

```
variable = random.randrange(1,10)

if 0 <= variable < 3:
   then do this
if 3 <= variable < 5:
   then do this
if 5 <= variable < 9:
   then do this
```

Comment: Turn based would be easy enough to set up, the game is more like this. Each player picks a class and each class has a different chance of attacking. Class 1(1 attack chance), Class 2(2 attack chances), Class 3(3 attack chances)... and the the players get the choice to choose between these classes so the code to choose who attacks must be dynamic.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean in your comment here - strategically speaking, why would anyone choose Class 1 or Class 2?

Comment: With lower attack chance comes great delt damage so depending on how the player wants to go they can pick a class with high damage ,but low chance of actually attacking, low damage but a very good chance of attacking or something in between (a "balance class" if you will)